# Responsive Design with HTML Tables, make first Column appear

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I currently have a problem making my HTML table responsive.

I have a html table where I have 4 columns, each with 25% width. On the desktop, the table looks great.

The first column has 10 rows, in each row there's a description text. The next 3 columns are product columns, where each one of them has a product with some information about it.

Since I can't show that many columns on a mobile phone, I'd like to basically have only the first column (description) + a product column shown on my mobile phone. Because otherwise, people don't know what the information stands for in the product column.

I hope someone can help me, thanks!

I already made up the table with the CSS, and tried to make each column 50% on mobile phones.
But the problem is that the first column should appear next to every product column.

Here is what I already have:

```
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class="col-25">Preview</th>
    <th class="col-25">Product 1</th>
    <th class="col-25">Product 2</th>
    <th class="col-25">Product 3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th class="col-25">Description</th>
    <td class="col-25">Product name 1</td>
    <td class="col-25">Product name 2</td>
    <td class="col-25">Product name 3</td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
    <th class="col-25">Price</th>
    <td class="col-25">Product price 1</td>
    <td class="col-25">Product price 2</td>
    <td class="col-25">Product price 3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.col-25 {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Please add a relevant code snippet of what you have already tried. SO is not a code writing service

Comment: Added the relevant code, sorry for the inconveniences!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is kind of tricky but I have a few solutions for your problem.

1. Try to use CSS breakpoints

   If your device hits a certain width you hide the following columns.

   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp
2. Use Bootstrap

   Bootstrap has already breakpoints built-in. You could build your table with their fantastic grid system.

   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

If you would post your example, I could take a further look but I think these two tips should give you an idea of how you can solve this problem yourself.

(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: another way (easy but not that pretty) is using `overflow-x: scroll`. I made another example here https://codepen.io/Throvn/pen/JVRGxj)

Comment: Yeah, I also thought of that, but isn‘t there a better way to implement this?